# $wpdb selects wrong database

Tags: plugins, wpdb

I have created a new WordPress site in a folder inside of another WordPress site.

Example
- mainsite.com
 - mainsite.com/secondsite

I have created a plugin and I use `$wpdb` to insert data to the database and the plugin inserts the data to the database of the first/parent site.

The code I use to include `$wpdb` is the following:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include $path . '/wp-load.php';
include $path . '/wp-config.php';
include $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
global $wpdb;
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` is not going to include `secondsite`. So all the files, including `wp-config.php` with the database details, are coming from the root public directory.

To get the current directory, including subdirectories, use any of these:

```
getcwd();

dirname(__FILE__);

basename(__DIR__);
```

But if your file is in a deeper  folder, you can't find the `secondsite` directory without specifying it (or scanning directories to find a WordPress installation). So you need to manually specify it like so:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/secondsite';
```

But your problem is that you're doing AJAX wrong. You shouldn't be sending AJAX requests directly to a file in your plugin. You should be [using the AJAX hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) or [adding a custom endpoint to the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Comment: i change $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with getcwd and still the same.

Comment: Hang on. Where is this file? Why are you including these files at all if it's a plugin?

Comment: this file is in a php file inside the plugin folder which updates a database table when an ajax event occurs. if i dont include the wp-load i canot use wpdb because i get an error

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: i have done this too and still the same. in another file i have in the plugin and use the same exact code i get the correct datatabase

Comment: Just do AJAX properly and you won't have this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74858/discussion-between-agis-soleas-and-jacob-peattie).

Comment: j.ajax({ 
url: "../wp-content/plugins/folder/update_game.php", 
method:"POST", 
data:{apotel:apotel,idagwna:ida}, 
success: function(result){ 
alert(result); 
location.reload(); 
}});
the ajax is working fine. because the result i get is from the file i want.

Comment: You realise `../wp-content/plugins/folder/update_game.php` is going to load the file from the site in the root directory right? You need to include `secondsite` in the URL. You should be doing AJAX the proper way in WordPress by following the links I sent you. You avoid all these issues with subdirectories and `$wpdb` if you do that.

Comment: it loads the correct file because when i make a change in that file i see the result in the alert i have in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

There are to major problems with your code.

First one is that you clearly include files of main/parent WordPress:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include $path . '/wp-load.php';
include $path . '/wp-config.php';
```

The above part of code will include mainsite.com/wp-config.php, so the rest of your code will connect to DB of that site - that is what your code should be doing...

If you'd like to connect to correct DB, then you should use something like this:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/secondsite'; // <- change it to proper folder name
include $path . '/wp-load.php';
include $path . '/wp-config.php';
include $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';

global $wpdb;
```

Now, when used on secondsite, it will connect to correct DB, but... **This code still isn't correct...**

You should never create PHP files that will process requests this way. All AJAX requests should be processed by `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` or by REST API.

Here is article from Codex explaining how to use AJAX in plugins properly:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins